# Recursively calling an anonymous function without using arguments.callee

Tags: javascript

How can I call an anonymous function recursively (from within itself)?

```
(function(n) {
    console.log(n=n-1);
    // Want to call it recursively here without naming any function
})(20);
```

Comment: Why no naming? You can create a function and use callback function to have dynamic code

Comment: i agree. You *can* have self invoking functions and *still* give them names. It's not mutually exclusive, it's just rare. You could write `(function test(n){console.log(n);}(20));`

Comment: What is the point of this? Is this for a challenge or something, or is there a real-world reason for why you can't name the function? There is a way of doing this (mentioned in the question linked) but performance for it isn't too quick.

Answer (score 5):

Just name it. In this context the function won't be available outside of parentheses anyway - so you won't be polluting the namespace with it.

```
(function recursive(n) {
  console.log(n = n - 1);
  if (n > 0) {
    recursive(n); // just an example
  }
})(20); 

//recursive(20); // won't be able to call it here...
```

Answer (score 2):

From the pure theoretical standpoint, if you really want to avoid *any* names, you can use the "Y combinator", which is basically a way to call a function with itself as an argument:

```js
(function (le) {
    return (function (f) {
        return f(f);
    }(function (f) {
        return le(function (x) {
            return f(f)(x);
        });
    }));
})(function (f) {
    return function (n) {
        document.write(n + " ");
        if (n > 0) f(n - 1);
    }
})(20);
```

Here's a [good explanation](https://blog.jcoglan.com/2008/01/10/deriving-the-y-combinator/) on how this works.

Comment: +1, probably not practical but very interesting (and actually answering the question!). Here's nice quote from the explanation: "*The frustrating thing about Y is that once you’ve derived it, **it’s totally impossible to tell what it does just by looking at it**. If you made it this far, congratulations.*"

Comment: avoid any names? what about le and f?

Comment: @rookie: those are function arguments, not function names. There are no function names used at all - they stay *truly* anonymous in this solution.

Comment: @bardzusny, i know, but arguments are still variables, and for avoiding one function name,`(function (d) {
   return (function (c) {
    return c(c);
   }(function (b) {
    return d(function (a) {
     return b(b)(a);
    });
   }));
  })(function (e) {
   return function (n) {
    document.write(n + " ");
    if (n > 0) e(n - 1);
   }
  })(20);` you get 5 variables (in the above example only 2), to handle with.

Answer (score 1):

You will not be able to call it without name of without using `arguments.callee`. However you can name a function this way:

```
(function repeat(n) {
    console.log(n);
    n = n - 1;
    if (n > 0) repeat(n);
})(20);
```